# How to take decision while developing web application using microservices in spring-boot for common code and relationship

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, microservices, entity-relationship

I am going to develop small web application to get an idea of micro-services architecture, using spring-boot and spring-data-jpa.

At initial stage, I have only 2 entities (1) CountryEntity and (2) StateEntity. In monolithic structure which already I have, there is a relationship between these 2 entities like :

CountryEntity:

```
@Entity
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper=false)
public class CountryEntity  extends BaseEntity{

    private String countryCode;
    private String country;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "country", orphanRemoval = true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<StateEntity> stateEntities;
}
```

StateEntity :

```
@Entity
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper=false)
public class StateEntity extends BaseEntity {

    private String stateCode;
    private String state;

    @ManyToOne
    private Country country;
}
```

Also, please notice that I have extends BaseEntity which contains shared fields like :

BaseEntity :

```
@MappedSuperclass
@Data
public abstract class BaseEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private Date createdDateTime;
    private Date updatedDateTime;
    private Boolean isActive;
    private Boolean isDelete;

    @PrePersist
    private void setCreatedDateTime() {
        this.createdDateTime = new Date();
        this.isActive = true;
        this.isDelete = false;
    }

    @PreUpdate
    private void setUpdatedDateTime() {
        this.updatedDateTime = new Date();
    }
}
```

Now, I have 2 queries while converting above monolithic structure to microservices as describe here :

**1.** Should I create shared library (separate microservice for shared code and then add dependency in all different microservices app)  for BaseEntity defined above and other classes like Constants, Utility etc.? or I should repeat all the code in all microservices? Please guide because  some sites are suggesting for shared library and some experts are advice not to use shared library and suggesting to repeat all the code. What should I do for better architecture.

**2.** How can I give relationship between above 2 entities in microservices architecture? I gone through SO questions and some feedback says that it is not possible. Then I have an application, in which all entities are in a relation directly or indirectly. Here, I have just take an example from original application. I know it must be some structure or some way, with which I can apply relation-ship. Please guide me.

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: I really depends on your project. Since you're working on a small-scale private one, you should be ok with just copying your code. Since it's for learning purposes anyway IIUC, why not try both approaches and compare them? In a larger project, you'd probably want to install some sort of versioning system and a documentation server where the common data structures can be accessed, so each service can check whether its current implementation is up to date/compatible.

Comment: There are only opinionated answers for your first question, there isn't a "better architecture". That's exactly why you see contradictions when you visited those sites, and why the answer that is posted here says A and the comments/downvotes say otherwise. Your second question is one of the things you have to solve in a different way with microservices, but covering those will lead to very broad answers.

Answer (score -1):

When you are working in Microservices architecture, you should put all common code into a `shared` module. This module can be deployed as a library to your Maven or any other repository and injected to your microservices on demand.

If you make a copy of code into your microservices - it will be harder to maintain it further. Imagine 100 microservices, which have a common class inside, and you want to change it. It will be even harder when you decide to split microservices into different repositories.

But you should be very careful when using Spring REST repository. When you inject into your microservice common repository for any entity, it will automatically expose it to REST, so you'll have the same REST points on different microservices, that's not good. There are may be troubles with Spring Security (if you forgot to hide it somewhere).

Comment: Yeah but if you make a common module, all the client modules still will need to be updated to the new dependency version when the shared data structures change, so this is not always the way to go.

Comment: Please go through blogs of Philipp Hauer's Blog at https://phauer.com/2016/dont-share-libraries-among-microservices/ - It clearly mention that don't use shared code and also state that “Duplication is better than the wrong abstraction”. I am confused.

Comment: @daniu It is much easier to update dependency, especially, if you are taking them from common parent.

Comment: @DDovzhenko : Main objective of microservices architecture is to achieve loosely coupled code as much as possible. And Shared libraries tightly couples microservices together.

Comment: @ChiragShah got it. Still, have the same side. If you change business logic - why shouldn't it be updated on all microservices? What if the old version is incorrect? If you change entities, it may be harder to update all DBs, especially if it is SQL, but when you add  a field to a Mongo entity - it will be easily added to all running DBs.

Comment: @ChiragShah I'm not sure if the coupling is bad among microservice architecture, as far as you properly split functionality between them.

Comment: @ChiragShah I'd say you should do the same approach for all entities/business logic, but should decide on each change whether it is critical to maintaining the same version of logic on all microservices, or there may be a difference in future.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194360/discussion-between-chirag-shah-and-ddovzhenko).